# Error in extending list

Tags: java, list

In my folder i have

DList.java,List.java

when I try to compile DList.java I get the following error.

```
DList.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class DList extends List {
                           ^
  symbol: class List
DList.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
  protected DListNode head;
```

My DList.java looks like the following

```
/* DList.java */


package list;
public class DList extends List {
    System.out.printf("testing");
}
```

Can anyone point out why is not working? I am very perplex. I followed word by word from my lecture.

Comment: Have you imported `List`? Right now it is not defined anywhere (hence: "cannot find symbol").

Comment: Please post also the definition of `List` class.

Comment: @jsalonen It looks like `DList` and `List` are in the same package ("In my folder I have"), so importing shouldn't be needed (barring confusion with `java.util.List`).

Comment: Is that `java.util.List`?

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one List class. You declared your own, but there is also a Java.util.List. You can specify which one you meant to use by providing the fully qualified name.

**Example**

My project is called Assignment1. I have two classes, MyList and List.

```
public class MyList extends Assignment1.List { }
```